# Performance testing : meaningful graph of a 3 variable statistic result

Tags: java, performance, statistics

I'm performing performance testing of a computer application (JAVA). The test concerns the response time (t) obtained while testing the application with a certain number of concurrent threads (th) and a certain amount of data (d).

Suppose I have the following results:

```
+------+-------+-----+
|  th  |   d   |  t  |
+------+-------+-----+
|   2  |   500 |  A  |
+------+-------+-----+
|   4  |   500 |  B  |
+------+-------+-----+
|   2  |  1000 |  C  |
+------+-------+-----+
|   4  |  1000 |  D  |
+------+-------+-----+
```

How can i benefit the most of these results such as knowing the limit of my app as well as creating meaningful graphs to represent these results.

I'm not a statistics person so pardon my ignorance. Any suggestions would be really helpful (even related statistics technical keywords I can Google).

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The tricky part for me was to determine the application's performance evolution taking both the number of threads and the amount of data into consideration in one plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way, check the following example I made with paint (the numbers I picked are just random):
[image: Threads and Data VS time]

Comment: the following example...? I can't see the image.

Comment: that's the image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNKQD.jpg
try to refresh the page or something.. Something's wrong on your side.

Comment: it must be the proxy then, I'll see it when i get home. thanks a lot and sorry for the trouble.